# can't run sudo commands in 20.04 it askes for a command yet no keyboard works to enter my password

Tags: keyboard, login, sudo

I would like to run sudo commands yet every time I try it askes me to login and I can't type in the terminal window and I can't enter my password using alt+f2, same for ctrl+alt+f2. could you please help me?

Comment: When you type a password into Terminal, you will not see any letters or asterisks to show that input was received. You simply type your password and press [Enter].

Answer (score 0):

When typing your password in terminal (this doesn't just apply to sudo, every cli app I've personally used which prompts for a password also has the same behaviour) no characters will be written on screen. Don't be worried, you are typing them though, simply type your password and press enter once you're finished. If you got it wrong it'll tell you.

Comment: thanks for telling me this I must have been getting it wrong